# Choosing AWS Lambda runtime option in terms of memory usage/cost for media encoding

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I'm evaluating some scenarios for my needs with media extraction from mp4 video files to mp3 using AWS lambda approach.

The main requirement is once a new mp4 file is available or saved in some S3 bucket by a custom application the Lambda function will be triggered and send metadata to Dynamo DB and then the lambda function will extract the audio and store it in another S3 bucket.

There are available four options as described below to design the Lambda function:

1. For example, use Java plus JAVE encoder library to do the job (with
   embed  ffmpeg binary in the lib/jar)
2. Use NodeJS with some npm package with media encode capacity
   (including spawn ffmpeg process)
3. Use NodeJS with AWS Elastic Transcode Service
4. Use Java with AWS Elastic Transcode Service

Which of option above will result in less cost in terms of resource (memory/cpu usage tiers)?

I’m guessing the two initial scenarios sound more amateur but could be less expensive. But I have doubt if in terms of memory and CPU resources usage choosing between NodeJS  or Java could affect the amount lost because of memory or the time execution of a lambda function will take to to the task.

I need care about these aspects it is desirable to spend the less amount as possible with AWS Lambda for this kind of task?

Doesn't matter choosing between NodeJs or Java?

Should I consider use the Elastic Transcode Service instead a custom library in lambda function?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The cost really depends on your throughput and the length of your content. Remember, currently `Lambda` has [execution timeout and other limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html).

I think the Java option will actually be more memory intense than the Node.js approach. I'd probably go with `Elastic Transcode` since it's managed and may be much easier to develop and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at some test results:

[AWS Lambda cold start (pseudo-)benchmark](https://github.com/berezovskyi/lambda-test)

Hope this helps